# Breaking change in LibGitSharp v0.17

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp, gitsharp

I am new to libgit sharp library. I have a line of code that works with v0.15 of libgit sharp. I have updated the package to the latest version 0.22. 
Repository.Network.FetchHeads.FirstOrDefault()

FetchHeads is deprecated in v0.17 (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/CHANGES.md).

Here is the snippet that I want to rewrite

```
var latestRemoteHead = repo.Network.FetchHeads.FirstOrDefault();
if (latestRemoteHead != null){
    var latestRemoteHeadCommit = (Commit)latestRemoteHead.Target;
    repo.Reset(ResetMode.Hard, latestRemoteHeadCommit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FetchHead` was indeed deprecated in [commit c7e11bbff588c0f2b84b3f9dbdfaf2e5ef00cf91](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/c7e11bbff588c0f2b84b3f9dbdfaf2e5ef00cf91), as part of the [Expand Merge API PR #643](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/643/commits):

- Deprecate `Network.Fetchheads`, `Repository.MergeHeads` as these should be
  internal only.
- Introduce ability to pull the configured upstream branch for the current
  branch

[Commit 35ea14d](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/commit/35ea14dd55582ba1dc4a8ad98e77ae656ee307e9) in April 2014 for libgit2sharp 0.18 set [the FetchHead class as internal](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blame/3615df921ded6e58b08bc438645d9291804f5db1/LibGit2Sharp/FetchHead.cs#L10).

You would need to list all the remote branches and check their HEAD commits in order to get back what you had from FetchHeads.

As a first clue, see [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/ExpectedFetchState.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/3615df921ded6e58b08bc438645d9291804f5db1/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/TestHelpers/ExpectedFetchState.cs#L107) to list the `branch.Tip.Id`